# Is possible change priority to task create_snapshot from NORMAL to HIGH or URGENT?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, filebeat, metricbeat

I has a cluster elasticsearch with *6 data nodes* and *3 master*.

When execute the snapshot I receive the error "**process_cluster_event_timeout_exception**".

I look in my cluster "*/_cat/pending_tasks*" it has 69 tasks with priority **HIGH** and source **put-mapping**

My cluster is for centralized log and have this process to put data in cluster:

- logstash - collect from Redis and put to Elasticsearch
- apm-server
- filebeat
- metricbeat

I stay removing beats and some applications from apm-server

**Is possible change priority to task create_snapshot from *NORMAL* to *HIGH* or *URGENT*?**

**It is not a solution**, how to I check the correct size for my cluster?

*Normally i keep 7 days the indice in my cluster because the backup.
But because the error, I removed the process to exclude the old data

*GET _cat/nodes?v&s=node.role:desc*

| ip | heap.percent | ram.percent | cpu | load_1m | load_5m | load_15m | node.role | master | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.0.2.8 | 47 | 50 | 0 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | mi | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-020 |
| 10.0.0.7 | 14 | 50 | 0 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | mi | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-0ab |
| 10.0.1.1 | 47 | 77 | 29 | 1.47 | 1.72 | 1.66 | mi | * | prd-elasticsearch-i-0e2 |
| 10.0.2.7 | 58 | 95 | 19 | 8.04 | 8.62 | 8.79 | d | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-0b4 |
| 10.0.2.4 | 59 | 97 | 20 | 8.22 | 8.71 | 8.76 | d | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-00d |
| 10.0.1.6 | 62 | 94 | 38 | 11.42 | 8.87 | 8.89 | d | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-0ff |
| 10.0.0.6 | 67 | 97 | 25 | 8.97 | 10.45 | 10.47 | d | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-01a |
| 10.0.0.9 | 57 | 98 | 32 | 11.63 | 9.64 | 9.17 | d | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-005 |
| 10.0.1.0 | 62 | 96 | 19 | 10.45 | 9.53 | 9.31 | d | - | prd-elasticsearch-i-088 |

**My cluster definitions:**

```json
    {
      "_nodes": {
        "total": 9,
        "successful": 9,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "cluster_name": "prd-elasticsearch",
      "cluster_uuid": "xxxx",
      "timestamp": 1607609607018,
      "status": "green",
      "indices": {
        "count": 895,
        "shards": {
          "total": 14006,
          "primaries": 4700,
          "replication": 1.98,
          "index": {
            "shards": {
              "min": 2,
              "max": 18,
              "avg": 15.649162011173184
            },
            "primaries": {
              "min": 1,
              "max": 6,
              "avg": 5.251396648044692
            },
            "replication": {
              "min": 1,
              "max": 2,
              "avg": 1.9787709497206705
            }
          }
        },
        "docs": {
          "count": 14896803950,
          "deleted": 843126
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 16778620001453
        },
        "fielddata": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 4790672272,
          "evictions": 0
        },
        "query_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 7689832903,
          "total_count": 2033762560,
          "hit_count": 53751516,
          "miss_count": 1980011044,
          "cache_size": 4087727,
          "cache_count": 11319866,
          "evictions": 7232139
        },
        "completion": {
          "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
          "count": 155344,
          "memory_in_bytes": 39094918196,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes": 31533157295,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 5574613712,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes": 449973760,
          "points_memory_in_bytes": 886771949,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 650401480,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 905283962,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 1173400,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 12580800,
          "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": 1607606224903,
          "file_sizes": {}
        }
      },
      "nodes": {
        "count": {
          "total": 9,
          "data": 6,
          "coordinating_only": 0,
          "master": 3,
          "ingest": 3
        },
        "versions": [
          "6.8.1"
        ],
        "os": {
          "available_processors": 108,
          "allocated_processors": 108,
          "names": [
            {
              "name": "Linux",
              "count": 9
            }
          ],
          "pretty_names": [
            {
              "pretty_name": "CentOS Linux 7 (Core)",
              "count": 9
            }
          ],
          "mem": {
            "total_in_bytes": 821975162880,
            "free_in_bytes": 50684043264,
            "used_in_bytes": 771291119616,
            "free_percent": 6,
            "used_percent": 94
          }
        },
        "process": {
          "cpu": {
            "percent": 349
          },
          "open_file_descriptors": {
            "min": 429,
            "max": 9996,
            "avg": 6607
          }
        },
        "jvm": {
          "max_uptime_in_millis": 43603531934,
          "versions": [
            {
              "version": "1.8.0_222",
              "vm_name": "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
              "vm_version": "25.222-b10",
              "vm_vendor": "Oracle Corporation",
              "count": 9
            }
          ],
          "mem": {
            "heap_used_in_bytes": 137629451248,
            "heap_max_in_bytes": 205373571072
          },
          "threads": 1941
        },
        "fs": {
          "total_in_bytes": 45245361229824,
          "free_in_bytes": 28231010959360,
          "available_in_bytes": 28231011147776
        },
        "plugins": [
          {
            "name": "repository-s3",
            "version": "6.8.1",
            "elasticsearch_version": "6.8.1",
            "java_version": "1.8",
            "description": "The S3 repository plugin adds S3 repositories",
            "classname": "org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3RepositoryPlugin",
            "extended_plugins": [],
            "has_native_controller": false
          }
        ],
        "network_types": {
          "transport_types": {
            "security4": 9
          },
          "http_types": {
            "security4": 9
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Data Nodes: 6 instances r4.4xlarge

Master Nodes: 3 instances m5.large

Comment: I have a topic in elastic community: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/queuing-tasks-and-snapshot-operation-not-working/258286

Answer (score 1):

No It is not possible to change priority of task create_snapshot.

As you have 69 pending tasks, it seems you are doing too many mapping updates.

Regarding **correct size of cluster**, I would recommend you to go through following blog posts :

1. https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-sizing-elasticsearch
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/sizing-domains.html